# Calculate correct height of div based on different children in slider?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby

I have a slider in a `<div>`. The slider takes an array of slides and each element has a text where there is no word-limit on the text. When I slide left or right, and the different texts are of different lengths, the height of the `<div>` varies, making it look ugly. I tried using a `min-height` or a `fixed height`, but those don't solve the problem, since there will either be too much empty space underneath the text, or, a text once in a while will be longer than the min-height and the size of the `<div>` will vary again.

What could I do now? Is there a way for me to find out what maximum height the div should have (based on what's the longest text in my array of slides) and then give my div this height? This way there would still be some empty space with the shorter texts, but at least it wouldn't be arbitrary.

Does this sound like an ok solution? I am wondering how I can measure this beforehand though? So I'm thankful for any clues!

Comment: Show us your code so far so that we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your situation, you have a `<div>` element that wraps multiple "slide elements" where;

- each slide element varies in height based on their text content and,
- you'd like the wraping div to natually expand to fit around all slides regardless of the arbitrary height of their content

One solution to this would be to use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) which would allow your slides to be arranged horizontally within the wrapper div, while also ensuring that the wrapper naturally expands to fit around it's children (of arbitrary height).

To illustrate this approach, consider the following example where flex box is used to ensure the pink div correctly wraps green slides (of differing height):

```css
#wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  overflow-x:scroll;      
  background:pink;
}

#wrapper > div {
  min-width:30rem;
  margin:1rem;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div><p>Short</p></div>
  <div><p>Tallest<br>Tallest<br>Tallest<br>Tallest<br>Tallest</p></div>
  <div><p>Tall<br>Tall<br>Tall</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use flex display to achieve this. Not sure if it will work with your slider tho, since tho have not posted your code.
You can find an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_equal_height_flexbox)